# Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features

Tags: android, java-8

После добавления в *build.gradle* следующих строк:

```
android {
  ...
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

получаю ошибку:

> Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features.
>   Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

При этом я не включала Jack, в *build.gradle* у меня нет (и не было никогда)

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

В чём может быть причина того, что я получаю эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать блок compileOptions в скрипте gradle для того, чтоб явно указать какой уровень(ver) языка использовать компилятору, вы указали JAVA8.

```
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```

Jack компилятор, по дефолту не подключен, но для работы именно в нем была поддержка 8-ки, с урезанным функционалом, именно поэтому у вас была соответствующая ошибка.

> Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features.

В новой SDK с новым gradle с 3.0.0-alpha1 и выше нет такой необходимости, потому что между компиляторами javac и dexс, там где находился jack, сейчас после .class лежит desugar прослойка как thirdLibrary и она уже вшита.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Поэтому так получилось что вы обновили, Gradle, SDK. Вы не указывали jack блок, иначе вам пришлось бы его удалить и у вас всё запустилось. А в коробке у вас произошла такая магия.

Но аналогично Jack, вы можете отключить Desugar в gradle.properties:

```
android.enableDesugar=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Как говорит документация:

> Для использования новых возможностей языка Java 8 необходимо также использовать новый набор инструментов Jack. С его помощью Android компилирует языковой источник Java в считываемый Android байткод Dalvik Executable (dex). В Jack предусмотрен собственный формат библиотеки .jack, большинство функциональных возможностей набора инструментов предоставляется в рамках одного инструмента: перекомпоновка, сжатие, обфускация и использование нескольких файлов DEX.

Если перевести весь этот "бред" на русский язык, то звучит примерно так:

> Если хотите использовать возможности Java 8 (лямбда выражения, повторяющиеся аннотации и дефолтные методы в интерфейсах), то будьте добры использовать jack - иначе не взлетит.

Comment: Так вроде офиц. док-ция говорит, что "Jack toolchain is deprecated" ((https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html).

Comment: Но вообще ошибка пропала после обновления gradle и android plugin)